# how to serialize oledbconnection object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, oledbconnection

I want to store OleDbConnection object in session which has mode="StateServer" or mode="sqlserver" but while trying this I am getting error, which says- unable to serialize the session state. In stateserver and sqlserver mode asp.net will serialize the session state objects and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef are not permitted.

Comment: That is a bad idea, don't do it. Database connections should be as short lived as possible. Use them and dispose them, do not keep them around longer than necessary. Your only viable option is to store the connection string if it is specific to the user.

Comment: completely agree with @Igor

Comment: @Igor Not always, there is something to be said for a _warm, ready-to-go_ connection for some use cases.  Not that I'm vouching for it to go into a session

Comment: @MickyD - I disagree especially in an asp.net setting where you do not know if the next request is even going to come in (*if it worked it would potentially leave a lot of open connections to the DB laying around*). Also it really can't be done. Serialization is the act of preserving state to be restored later but an open connection to the database is not something that can be captured and restored later.

Comment: @Igor I'm not referring to asp.net which is why I said _"some use cases"_.  We saw a marked improvement in our back-end where the just the cost of _opening a DB connection_ was much larger than 2 WCF hops **and** the actual SQL task.  So we introduced a true DB connection pool to our system and there was much rejoicing, to quote _Monty Python_.

Comment: I am using MTS transaction which not let me to enlist a new connection. That is why I am storing connection in the session.

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: write a windows service that holds the connection open and enlists in MTS transactions. then use tcp, named pipes or shared memory to interact between ASP.NET server side and that service. there is no point involving client http requests with MTS transactions.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense whatsoever to want to serialize a database connection. A resource like that is inherently not serializable, thus cannot be saved in the session.

Storing a database connection in the session worked using the InProc session mode, because that merely stores references to objects, while every other session mode uses serialization: writing the public properties to a file or database in a particular format. This does not preserve network connections.

Simply do not store a database connection in the session and you'll be fine. Do not reinvent the already existing wheel called "connection pooling". You do not need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is behavior by design. The `DbConnection` implementations are not marked `Serializable` for good reasons - the most important one would be that open connections hold unmanaged live socket or pipe handles.

From an application design point of view, storing a live connection in a session would make no sense. Also, keeping connections open across request can impair performance. Database connections are pooled, creating and opening a new connection will internally reuse an existing one from the pool (if properly configured) so it is the most efficient and recommended way to open/close one connection per request.

If you - for whatever reason - have session-dependent connections, store the connection strings (or an index pointing to a set of those) instead of the actual connection object.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738199/1132334,
https://forums.asp.net/t/1790135.aspx?SQL+connection+best+practices